# My spy is being called but my function is not being covered in karma coverage

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a `sidenav` component and inside i have a `header` component:

```
<div>
   <app-header id="header" (openSidenavEmitter)="openSidenav()"></app-header>
</div>
```

My header component have a event emitter that when the user click in the hamburg icon, it emits a event to parent component to open the sidenav:

```
@Output() openSidenavEmitter = new EventEmitter();
openSidenav() {
   this.openSidenavEmitter.emit()
}
```

In my `sidenav` component, when i receive this event, i call a function `openSidenav()` to set true to variable `showSidenav`:

```
openSidenav() {
   this.showSidenav = true;
}
```

I'm trying to make a unit test that cover the function `openSidenav()`. My spy is being called, my test is passing but my function is still not be covering in karma coverage report.
This is my test:

```
it('should open sidenav when user click in hamburg icon', () => {
   const spyOnOpenSidenav = spyOn(component, 'openSidenav')
   const header = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#header'));
   header.triggerEventHandler('openSidenavEmitter', {});
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(spyOnOpenSidenav).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

How i can cover this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest updating your test to the following:

```js
it('should open sidenav when user click in hamburg icon', () => {
   const spyOnOpenSidenav = spyOn(component, 'openSidenav').and.callThrough()
   ...
}
```

What may be happening is that you are calling your method, which has a spy on it.
Because of the spy being placed on the method, it will not actually execute unless you tell it.

To ensure the method continues the execution you should use the `and.callThrough()` method.

Additionally, if you want to ensure your test is completly covering your function you check that the value of `openSidenav` changes to `true`.

This is a very simple function, but if you had more behaviour that could change the value of `openSidenav` you wouldn't know if the test was successfull without looking at the final value.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for.